# advanced grep(/perl)-like text-file processing on win32

Tags: windows, makefile, cmd

To port a GNU makefile to the (non-cygwin) win32 platform, I am looking for a way to scan source files for the patterns such as '1234 // $RESOURCE$ "my_image.ico"', to then be appended to a resource file in the format '1234 ICON "my_image.ico"'. Using perl this is can be accomplished as such:

`perl -nle 'print "$1 ICON $2" if /([0-9]+)\s*\/\/\s*\$RESOURCE\$\s*(\".*\")\s*$$/'`

On windows, the thing that just came close is `findstr`, but this only allows for matching, not outputting in the alternative form. Simply replacing the string constant in between should do it I guess.

Any clues on how to get this going, short of including my own perl/sed.exe in the distribution :)?

Answer (score 1):

You could use VBScript (or even PowerShell, though that's still somewhat rare to be default), if you're not desperately in need of a `cmd` solution.

I have a little trouble reading your regex here, but it looks like this (correct me if I'm wrong):

```
some-number // $RESOURCE$ ...something-else...
```

in which case you can couple `findstr` with `for /f` which can do tokenizing of the input:

```
for /f "usebackq tokens=1,2* delims=/ " %%a in (`findstr ... file`) do echo %%a ICON %%c
```

where `%%c` would be the third (and last) token (with delimiters being space and `/`) and `%%a` the first one.

I have no clue of Perl so this is a lot of guessing right now. Quick test:

```
> for /f "usebackq tokens=1,2* delims=/ " %a in ('123      //   $RESOURCE$ abc def') do @echo %a ICON %c

123 ICON abc def
```

The `2*` in the `tokens` option above will cause everything from the third token to be included, regardless of whether it has delimiting characters or not.

Hope this helps (a little at least).